# Ajax Call empty response on Google chrome Mobile

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome, xmlhttprequest, cors

i searched for an answer that fix my problem a lot, but none of the topic fit my scenario..

I have to make an AJAX call inside my application, it work fine on ALL desktop browser, and on SOME mobile browser (for example on my ASUS zenPhone native browser it work correctly, even on my iPhone from work (FF and Safari)) but no way in google Chrome (mobile), in this one the call *complete* but the response **it's empty** (only empty, no error provided)... i ask some friend to test it too and similar result occours (empty response) .... i have an https server and an https endpoint

there is my code:

```
<script>
var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10000000) + 2000);
var data = JSON.stringify({
  "Token": x,
  "Subject": "testAPI"
});

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();


xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function () {
  if (this.readyState === 4) {
    //console.log(this.responseText);
    var dataJ = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    var dataA = dataJ.Questions;
    alert(dataA[0].img);//this is already empty on my mobile :(
    dataA.forEach(function(entry) {
      //console.log(entry);
    });
  }
});

xhr.open("POST", url);
xhr.setRequestHeader("content-type", "application/json");
xhr.setRequestHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");

xhr.send(data);


</script>
```

Server side CORS are enabled, and as i said it works flawless on all desktop i tested on ... i don't know if i can provide the url to you guys(i have to ask @ the API provider) but if you give me some hints it would be nice ...

thanks a lot for your time!

[EDIT]

after some trouble i get an error(Testing remotly from my phone to my PC with dev tools)

Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE

on the other device i didn't get this error...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a long shot but, try to set the content type header to :

```
xhr.setRequestHeader("content-type", "text/plain");
```

This should suppress the CORS preflighting done by chrome which causing the empty response.

Comment: in this way the API don't accept the data - token anymore  .. and i cant' code the server side myself :(

Comment: Does it give you an error/access denied response when you change the content-type header?

Comment: yes ofc, i think it's a coded error (server side) : Error: duplicated token: undefined

Comment: turn out it was a certificate problem, server side.... i was able to find the error using the remote google console..

thanks for your time!